# Restrict function action to row operated by user

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't find a way to restrict the action triggered by `ng-change` to only the row operated by the user. So, if user selects "League" on dropdown 1, two dropdowns should be displayed on the "Available Items" column. The one from the top lets you select a sport, when selected, down dropdown should display league options. The problem now is that all dropdowns from the table get populated (you can see that if you select "league" on another row's dropdown, league options are already displayed before you select your sport). What I need is to restrict function's action only to row operated by user.

Here's a fiddle:

https://embed.plnkr.co/kAiLw40hUvnLk9jv86aj/

```
<div class="col-md-12 limitObjects">
 <h4>Limit Object: </h4>
  <div style="overflow: auto; max-height: 500px; height: 100%">
   <table border="0" class="table-bordered myTable" >
    <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="item in userMappings" ng-model="item">
      <td class="col-md-4">
        {{item.idsport}}, Game Type {{item.idgametype}}, {{item.name}} (Current limit {{item.value}}) {{item.mapped}}
      </td>
      <td class="col-md-3 mapType" style="padding-bottom: 25px; padding-left: 15px" >
       <h4>Mapping Type: <span style="font-size:0.8em">{{mapping.name}}</span> </h4> 
       <select ng-model="item.mapping" ng-change="which(item, $index, event)" ng-options="mapping.name for mapping in mappingType" se-change=''></select>
      </td>
      <td class="col-md-4" style="padding-bottom: 25px; padding-left: 10px">
       <h4>Available Items:</h4>
       <select ng-show="item.buau" ng-model="sport" ng-change="getID(sport, $index, $event); table($event)"  ng-options="sport.name for sport in sportsList"></select>
       <select ng-show="item.buau == false" ng-model="sportLeague" ng-change="getLeaguecategories(sportLeague, $index, $event)" ng-options="sportLeague.name for sportLeague in sportsList" style="float: left;"></select>
       <select ng-show="item.buau == false"  ng-model="selectedLeague" ng-change="getID(selectedLeague, $index)" ng-options="selectedLeague.name for selectedLeague in leagueList" ></select>
      </td>
      <td class="col-md-4" style="padding-bottom: 25px; padding-left: 15px">
       <h4>Subjects: </h4>
       <select ng-model="subject" ng-change="getsubjectID(subject, $index)" ng-options="subject.description for subject in limitSubject"></select>
      </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
<script>

 $scope.mappingType = [{name: "Sport"}, {name: "League"}, {name: "No Mapping"}];

 $scope.sportsList = [{id : 34, name : "[Default]"}, {id: 15, name : "Alpine Skiing"}, { id : 8,  name : "American Football" }, { id : 23,  name : "Australian Rules"}];

 $scope.getLeaguecategories = function($event){
    $scope.leagueList = [{"name": "NFL"}, {"name": "NCAA"}, {"name": "All others"}];
 }

 $scope.userMappings =[{"id":"1","idgametype":"81","idsport":"NFL","mapped":"0","name":"Side","online":"1","profilelimitkeyid":"1","value":"3000"},{"id":"2","idgametype":"81","idsport":"NFL","mapped":"4","name":"Total","online":"1","profilelimitkeyid":"1","value":"3000"},{"id":"3","idgametype":"81","idsport":"NFL","mapped":"0","name":"IfBets","online":"1","profilelimitkeyid":"1","value":"500"},{"id":"4","idgametype":"81","idsport":"NFL","mapped":"0","name":"MoneyLine","online":"1","profilelimitkeyid":"1","value":"2000"},{"id":"5","idgametype":"81","idsport":"NFL","mapped":"1","name":"Parlays","online":"1","profilelimitkeyid":"1","value":"700"},{"id":"6","idgametype":"81","idsport":"NFL","mapped":"0","name":"Related","online":"1","profilelimitkeyid":"1","value":"0"},{"id":"7","idgametype":"81","idsport":"NFL","mapped":"0","name":"Reverses","online":"1","profilelimitkeyid":"1","value":"500"},{"id":"8","idgametype":"81","idsport":"NFL","mapped":"2","name":"Teasers","online":"1","profilelimitkeyid":"1","value":"0"}];



$scope.which = function( item, index ) {
  if ( item.mapping.name === "Sport" ){
       item.buau = true;
  } else if ( item.mapping.name === "League" ) {
       item.buau = false;
  } else if ( item.mapping.name === "No Mapping" ){

  }
 }
```

Comment: Please post your detail code, it will be helpful for us to answer your question.

Comment: Hi Khalid Hussain, I updated the post.